# Missing something in for cycle evaluation (scala)

Tags: scala

I coded a function to enumerate permutation for a given list, but I can't understand why it consistently return an empty list instead of permutations.
May you help me understand?

```
def permutations(l: List[Any]): List[List[Any]] = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: tail => for {
    element <- l
    permutationOfRest <- permutations(l.filter( x => x != element))
  } yield  element :: permutationOfRest
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with first `case`. When input list is empty, you return an empty list or permutations. Instead of it, you should return list with no permutations:

```
case Nil => List(Nil)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I often get confused with map and flatMap